# Realtime database Rules Validate If Data With Value Exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to create rules denied if a price is already registered in the database?
I tried to validate using exist data but firebase blocks all of them when there is one data

```
database.ref('data/penawaran/enter-name').push({
    name: 'Udin',
    price:'300000',
    member_id:9,
    product_id:8,
    created_at: '2020-10-13 23:00:00'
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
       alert('error');
    } else {
       
    }
});
```

^^^
i want get failed cause price 300000 already exist in database

```
database.ref('data/penawaran/enter-name').push({
    name: 'Udin',
    price:'900000',
    member_id:9,
    product_id:8,
    created_at: '2020-10-13 23:00:00'
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
       alert('error');
    } else {
       
    }
});
```

i want get success cause price 900000 not  exist in database

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the rules by themselves don't do anything, you should edit the question to also show the app code that doesn't work the way you exepct.

Comment: hello im already edit the question and add the app code, thank you :)

Comment: We need to be able to see the [complete, minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We can't see how you build the reference, since we don't know what `roomName` is, or any of the other variables.  You should hard code all variables with actual values.

Comment: hello thank you, im already update my example code

Comment: There is no way to ensure a unique **value** in the database through security rules. I you want something to be unique, make it the key - since keys are by definition unique within their context.

Comment: thank you for information..  im trying change price to key ,, :)